# SLIM framework Halt call

Tags: php, frameworks, execution, slim, halt

Have a question on Slim Framework php.

In my application, I would like to stop the application execution if a condition is mismatched.

There is a halt function, per Slim documentation. But that does not appear to be working.
the application continuous to execute even after calling Halt.

pseudo code:

```
if ( $valid ) {
         // Do something
} else {
    $app->halt(500, "not valid");
}
// Other code here.


$app->run();
```

I was expecting that, we we call Halt function, the "Other code" should not execute.
But it does not appear to be the case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always call [`exit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) manually to stop the script execution.

```
$app->halt(500, "not valid");
exit;
```

Comment: Thats what I had been doing. But its not recommended by Slim guys. They are saying halt should take care of it. Here is the reference. [link](http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/questions/122-use-or-not-to-use-exit)

Comment: @KevinRave ah. Well I'm stumbled then.

Comment: Anyways, thats the only option now! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Halt should work. As Josh mentioned, it does need to be called from within a route callback. For example, I use the following as a custom 404 (inside of index.php) in the event that a specified route is not found.

```
    // not found (custom 404)
    $app->notFound(function () use ($app) {

            // build response
            $response = array(
                'type' => 'not_found',
                'message' => 'The requested resource does not exist.'
            );

            // output response
            $app->halt(404, json_encode($response));

    });
```

Note the reference to use ($app) -- more on this can be found here: http://www.slimframework.com/documentation/stable#scope-resolution

Answer (score 2):

Halt should only be invoked within the context of a route callback. I recommend you ask any further questions on the official Slim Framework support forum:

http://help.slimframework.com

Best regards,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

You can use return if you are in a callback function

```
return $app->halt(500,"message");
```

or

```
$app->stop();
```

after halt function.