# What is the correct way to redirect a request in middleware?

Tags: php, redirect, infinite-loop, middleware, slim

I am trying to implement the (in)famous [improved persistent session](http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice) as middleware in the Slim microframework.

There are some places in the algorithm described where the application should check the user's cookie and redirect the user if their cookie has expired or is invalid.  Unfortunately, it is impossible to redirect a user from within middleware, for two reasons:

1. Slim's `redirect` can only be used within named routes;
2. `redirect` will create an entirely new request, thus restarting the Slim application.  The same conditions that triggered the redirect before will be re-triggered, thus creating an infinite loop.

Problem 1 can be solved with clever use of hooks, but I am not sure what to do about problem 2.  I notice that [some middleware](https://github.com/jeremykendall/slim-auth) solves this by using a custom Exception, which they then catch with Slim's error handler, and then call the redirect:

```
// Handle the possible 403 the middleware can throw
$app->error(function (\Exception $e) use ($app) {
    ...
    if ($e instanceof HttpUnauthorizedException) {
        return $app->redirectTo('login');
    }
    ...
});
```

But I am not certain that this is the best way to do it.    Are there any other ways that I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you listed above is a perfectly fine way of doing it, and is generally how it's done.  Assuming your login page doesn't check for HttpUnauthorizedExcepion, there would be no way it could ever redirect loop.

Comment: Somehow, I completely forgot that I answered someone else's related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30852767/2970321